# Cover addError in Test Class

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I built a trigger to not let the user approve (change Status__c from SST Approved to BA Approved) an Opportunity without filling in Batch__c field.

Trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityApprovalValidation on Opportunity (before update) {
for(Opportunity Opp : Trigger.New)
{
    String oldStatus=Trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Status__c;
    if(Opp.Status__c=='BA Approved' && oldStatus=='SST Approved')
    {
        if((Opp.Batch__c==NULL) || (Opp.Batch__c!=NULL && Opp.Count_of_LineItems__c==0))
           {
               Opp.addError('You cannot approve an Opportunity without adding it to a Batch');
           }
    }
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class OpportunityApprovalValidationTest {
    @isTest static void testmeth() {
        
        Account acc = new Account();
        
        acc.Name = 'Trigger Test Account';
        acc.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        
        insert acc;
  
        Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity();
        
        Opp.Name = 'Test Opp for OppApprovalValidation Trigger';
        Opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
        Opp.Type = 'New';
        Opp.CloseDate = System.today() + 5;
        Opp.StageName = 'Learn';
        Opp.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        Opp.Startup_Approval_Status__c = 'SST Approved';
        
        
        insert Opp;
        Test.startTest();
        Opp.Startup_Approval_Status__c = 'BA Approved';
        Opp.PeopleSoft_Upload_Batch__c = null;
        
        Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(new Opportunity[] { opp }, false); // false = allow partial failure, no exception
        System.assertNotEquals(true, results[0].isSuccess(),'Opportunity should not have saved');
        Boolean properErrorReceived = false;
        for(Database.Error error: results[0].getErrors()) {
        properErrorReceived |= error.getMessage().containsIgnoreCase('You cannot approve an Opportunity without adding it to a Batch');
    }
    System.assert(properErrorReceived, 'We expected a different error message');
        Test.stopTest();
        }
       
    }
```

However, when I run the test, the code coverage is stuck at 66% and upon reviewing the error message, the issue is with the "Opp.addError" part of my trigger. Can someone please help me with the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is a trigger instead of a validation rule? If you insist on keeping this as a trigger (which requires a test), then you should make sure that the value your assertion expects from the exception message actually does match the message you're setting (they're currently not the same, which would lead to the assertion failing).

Comment: I initially tried achieving this using a validation rule but apparently, validation rules won't trigger on approval process or workflow field updates. Also, I tried your solution but unfortunately, I'm still getting the assertion failed error. "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: You cannot approve an Opportunity without adding it to a Batch". The error message is on line 24

Answer (score 1):

You can't hard-code ID values in a unit test (within some rare exceptions). You need to create a new Account and then use that Id:

```
Account testAccount = new Account(Name='Test');
insert testAccount;
...
Opp.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
...
```

For your unit test, don't use try-catch:

```
    insert Opp;
    Test.startTest();
    Opp.Status__c = 'BA Approved';
    Opp.Batch__c = null;
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(new Opportunity[] { opp }, false); // false = allow partial failure, no exception
    System.assertNotEquals(true, results[0].isSuccess(),'Opportunity should not have saved');
    Boolean properErrorReceived = false;
    for(Database.Error error: results[0].getErrors()) {
        properErrorReceived |= error.getMessage().containsIgnoreCase('you cannot approve an opportunity without adding it to a batch');
    }
    System.assert(properErrorReceived, 'We expected a different error message');
```

---

```
trigger OpportunityApprovalValidation on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity Opp : Trigger.New) {
        String oldStatus = Trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Status__c;
        if(Opp.Status__c=='BA Approved' && oldStatus=='SST Approved' && (Opp.Batch__c==NULL || Opp.Count_of_LineItems__c==0)) {
            Opp.addError('You cannot approve an Opportunity without adding it to a Batch');
        }
    }
}
```

---

Your code checks to see `Count_of_LineItems__c` is 0, but perhaps, for whatever reason, it's null? You may need to do additional debugging and/or set the correct value for the field in order to force the error to occur.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you've suggested but I still receiving an Assertion Failure. "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Opportunity should not have saved: Same value: true". I've updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. On removing assert Statement in test class it was giving 100% coverage. Later replace assert statement with below code.

```
catch(Exception e)
    {
        
      Boolean flag = (e.getMessage().contains('You cannot approve an Opportunity without adding it to a Batch')) ? true : false;

      System.AssertEquals(flag, true);

      }
```